# Very slow cypher query for friend recommendations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm relatively new to Neo4J and graph databases. I created a new database using v2.0 and populated it with 400,000 people nodes, and 20 million follow relationships between them. I run the query below to try to find "people who are being followed by the people I follow, who I don't already follow". The query is just painfully slow. I assumed it would be lightning fast since that seems to be Neo's forte.

Am I doing this wrong? Below is my query:

```
MATCH p=(a:person)-[:follows]->(:person)-[:follows]->(c:person)
WHERE a.id = 1000 AND NOT(a-[:follows]->c)
RETURN c.id, count(p) as count ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5;
```

It seems to run much faster if I limit the number of paths (there are approximately 40,000 in the query) using "WITH a,c,p LIMIT 10000" before getting to the aggregates, or remove the "NOT(a-[:follows]->c)". Unfortunately, I can't afford to do either of these.

Any advice I can get would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the result of my profile:

```
==> ColumnFilter(symKeys=["c.personname", "  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE2a433ee6-de88-4555-969c-6057f8b44b3c"], returnItemNames=["c.personname", "cnt"], _rows=5, _db_hits=0)
==> Top(orderBy=["SortItem(Cached(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE2a433ee6-de88-4555-969c-6057f8b44b3c of type Integer),false)"], limit="Literal(5)", _rows=5, _db_hits=0)
==>   EagerAggregation(keys=["Cached(c.personname of type Any)"], aggregates=["(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE2a433ee6-de88-4555-969c-6057f8b44b3c,Count(a))"], _rows=16044, _db_hits=0)
==>     Extract(symKeys=["  UNNAMED49", "a", "  UNNAMED50", "c", "  UNNAMED35"], exprKeys=["c.personname"], _rows=42439, _db_hits=42439)
==>       Filter(pred="NOT(nonEmpty(PathExpression((a)-[  UNNAMED78:follows]->(c), true)))", _rows=42439, _db_hits=0)
==>         TraversalMatcher(start={"label": "person", "query": "Literal(170096)", "identifiers": ["a"], "property": "personid", "producer": "SchemaIndex"}, trail="(a)-[  UNNAMED35:follows WHERE true AND true]->(  UNNAMED49)-[  UNNAMED50:follows WHERE true AND true]->(c)", _rows=51500, _db_hits=51786)
```

Comment: Is this from a cold or warmed cache? You may want to play with the object cache settings and possibly the memory mapped IO settings in neo4j.properties.

Comment: Would you mind using PROFILE command on your query and paste the results?

Comment: Is 
MATCH (me:person)-[:follows*2..2]->(reco:person)
WHERE me.id = 1000
RETURN  me.id, count(reco) AS count
doing what you want? Does it perform faster?

Comment: Have you created an index? `CREATE INDEX ON :person(id)`.

Comment: I have not changed the default settings. The performance is so bad (more than 10 secs with a "warmed" cache) that I immediately assumed there was something horribly wrong with my query. I do have an index on personid.

Comment: I've added the profile results to the original post. I'm not sure how to interpret it.

Comment: Rolf - Your suggested query was not giving me back the expected results. I modified it slightly to give me the top 5 recommendations based on the count of follow relationships, then added NOT(me-[:follows]->reco) to the WHERE clause, and that slowed it down considerably.

Comment: Something goes wrong with the first execution step, it should fetch `a` from index and other nodes by traversal (no db hits), but it hits db over 50000 times. Simplify like this and profile: `MATCH (a:person {id:1000})-[:follows]->()-[:follows]->(c) WHERE NOT a-[:follows]->c RETURN c.id, count(a) as cnt //etc`.

Comment: I updated the profile results based on the query you provided. I can't tell if it's any better.

Answer (score 0):

As best I can interpret that execution plan there are two bottle necks, indicated by high values for `_db_hits`. One of them is on account of (unnecessarily) reading property values for all the matched `(c)` nodes and then only return five. You can get around this by limiting the result to five before reading in the property values. Try imposing both order and limit in a `WITH` clause, then read and return properties for those five nodes. Something like this

```
MATCH (a:person {id:1000})-[:follows]->()-[:follows]->(c) 
WHERE NOT a-[:follows]->c 
WITH c, count(a) as cnt  //carry (c) instead of fetching (c.id)
    ORDER BY cnt
    LIMIT 5
RETURN c.id, cnt  //fetch (c.id) only for the five nodes you are actually interested in
```

The other bottle neck is the beginning of the query and I don't know what goes wrong there. I notice in the execution plan it names properties `personid` and `personname`, but the query you posted looked up node by a property called `id`. Are you sure that the property that you use to bind `(a)` is indexed for the `:person` label? You can type `:schema` in the browser or `schema` in the shell to list indices and confirm that whatever property you use in the query (`personid`, `id` or whatever) is listed for the `:person` label.

Comment: Sorry about the inconsistent property names. It should be personid, not id. I typed out the original query wrong in my original post. I'll try out your suggestion in using the WITH clause.